# MSACCESS SQL Compare values in 2 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables; table A and B. My data looks as follows below. I'm trying to do 2 things:

1. How many times the Last Name and Zip in table A match the Last Name and Zip in table B?
2. If Last Name and Zip in Table A match Last Name and Zip in table B, how often do their phone numbers match?

Table A
**Last Name..........Zip.....Phone**
Tester..............00000....555555555
Tester..............00000....111111111
Test................11111.....99999999

Table B
**Last Name..........Zip.....Phone**
Tester..............00000....555555555
Tester..............00000....111111111
Test................11111.....99999999

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the first answer

```
SELECT COUNT(A.Last Name) as namezipmatch
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME
WHERE
A.ZIP = B.ZIP
```

This should give you the second answer

```
SELECT COUNT(A.Last Name) as nameziphonematch
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.LAST_NAME = B.LAST_NAME
    WHERE
    A.ZIP = B.ZIP AND A.PHONE = B.PHONE
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps...  Can't recall if access lets you count distinct.

```
SELECT count(Distinct B.Last_name + B.Zip) as CntLastZip,
       count(Distinct C.Last_Name + C.Zip + C.Phone) as CntLastZipPhone
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN tableB
  ON A.Last_name = B.Last_Name
  AND A.Zip = B.ZIP
LEFT JOIN tableC
  ON A.Last_Name = C.Last-Name
  AND A.Zip=C.Zip
  AND A.Phone = C.Phone
```